# Larvel Project Bedrive - Install bedrive on subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

When i install bedrive. I am unable to go forward from Filesystem. .htaccess file is given below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But if i replace the .htaccess to this. Installation complete.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<Files "ngsw-worker.js">
    Header Set Service-Worker-allowed "/"
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

After this when i access to home page or admin page. .htaccess file error occured. Unable to fix this problem.

Comment: It will be helpful if you show the directory structure or where and how you installed the app.

Comment: i installed on subdomain.